# Storing 'dictionaries' and 'arrays' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for some advice on how to store 'arrays' and 'dictionaries'-type information in an SQL Server 2012 database. Up to now, I've been using the xml type, as I can query this easily, and they can be simply represented, e.g:

```
<Array><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i></Array>
<Dictionary><Item1>Value1</Item1><Item2>Value2</Item2></Dictionary>
```

Up until now, I assumed that the xml data type would benefit from PAGE compression but today I realised that isn't the case. This is a fairly big issue since the database will store hundreds of thousands of these records every day, and it seems much of the data will be this uncompressed XML.

So I'm looking for a workaround. I figure I may be able to tabulate this data. For example,  a data dictionary table:

```
[ID] bigint PK,
[OwnerID] bigint,
[Name] varchar(32),
[Value] varchar(32)
```

And an array:

```
[OwnerID] bigint PK
[Index] int PK
[Value] varchar(32)
```

This would work, but I'm worried about how 'queryable' this method would be - i.e. 'WHERE ObjectID's X dictionary properly = Y'. I could write a scalar function for this, but I know that'll cause performance issues.

I've read up on this particular issue, but the general consensus seems to be 'use an xml column and don't worry about it', but given the amount of data I need to allow for, I don't think this is an option for me.

Any advice or insights would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How much data do you have? I am doing a similar approach and I am up to the 10GBs of data. I am using .exists() and primary and secondary indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML column is a blob that allows queries on it...

As far as I remember, and at least up to SQL2008R2, Microsoft recommendations for XML columns were only use them when you are going to have sporadic searches to it, I think this is far from being your case.

Your data seems to be highly normalized so if you have good indexing to the tables I would suggest you going to tables like you pointed there.

Anyway if you are going to have tens of millions of rows a month, I rather suggest you partitioning the table to improve performance further more.

Finally, from a point of view of disk usage, and since you are planning for such volumes, the storage shouldn't be a concern at all, it should be a requirement (IMO).

Comment: I tested each option and came to the conclusion that the separate table approach is probably the best. It is generally slower than the XML column when getting individual dictionary items, but the tables are far smaller when compressed.